# Faster alternative to Pandas apply, text data

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe , two columns "text" and "status":

```
text,status
Great!!, pos
I dunno., neut
Bad.,neg
```

There are about 6000 rows.

Text field consists of short sentences. I did a

```
dataset["text"] = dataset["text"].apply(strip_punctuation)
```

where `strip_punctuation` makes some string operations and returns a string. Function works on strings fast, but when I put it in apply result is a disaster I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Merlin, I'm on cellphone, not a proper computer struggling to format ;)

Comment: What do you mean by the result is a disaster?

Comment: Can you include the strip_punctuation function

Comment: Possible Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: @Merlin , I don't have only punctuation stripping in the function, there are other string operations as well.

Comment: @cricket_007 ,  it processed 2400 rows in 2 hours?!? I fed sentences to the function by hand on the shell, every sentence takes less than 1 sec. I have zero idea what is going on.

Comment: "Function works on strings fast" clearly this can't be true.

Comment: @Andy Hayden sentences are short, at most 5-6 words. Function is a string processing function at the end but strings are short :)

Comment: Try dataset["text"] = map(strip_punctuation, dataset["text"])

Comment: @Merlin , I can't. It's part of a school work.

Comment: @Kevin K, what is difference here between apply and map by performance?

Comment: @dogacanb The built in map function should be able to perform the operation in parallel. Pandas is notorious for lacking parallelism.

Answer (score 4):

`DataFrame.apply` essentially does a sequential scan of the entire `DataFrame` and applies your function to each row. that is super slow if your `DataFrame` is big.

Using vectorized methods like follows can increase performance but you get a trade-off of more complexity/less functionality.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('someregextoremovepunctuation','')
```

Comment: Well, problem is that function is not only one regex operation, it has a sequence of regex replaces, splits...

Comment: @dogacanb But you should be able to rewrite it as a single regex. Of course, without the code it's hard to say...

Comment: It calls other functions as well.  I first lowercase the sentence, strip off some punctuations then do stemming. I can't stem with a regex :)